# Create adwords BigQuery Transfer with Python bigquery_datatransfer: error 400 Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, transfer, google-api-python-client

## My step：

1. Get Authorization code：I use this URL to get auth code

   `https://www.gstatic.com/bigquerydatatransfer/oauthz/auth?clientId=<id from list data sources>&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery`
2. Create a service account with Project Owner
3. Execute sample code：

```
def run_quickstart():
    from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer_v1
    from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Struct

    client = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.DataTransferServiceClient()

    project = <project-id>
    parent = client.location_path(project, 'us')
    params = Struct()
    params.update({
        "customer_id": <customer-id>
    })

    transfer_config = {
        "destination_dataset_id": "test",
        "display_name": "test",
        "data_source_id": "adwords",
        "params": params
    }

    authorization_code = <authorization_code from step 1>
    response = client.create_transfer_config(parent, transfer_config, authorization_code)
    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_quickstart()
```

Expect：Data transfer create
But I got the error：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 729, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "Request contains an invalid argument."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1581747953.387292000","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[2404:6800:4012:1::200a]:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"Request contains an invalid argument.","grpc_status":3}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 49, in <module>
    run_quickstart()
  File "app.py", line 40, in run_quickstart
    parent, transfer_config, authorization_code)
  File "/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_datatransfer_v1/gapic/data_transfer_service_client.py", line 563, in create_transfer_config
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
  File "/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument.
```

I couldn't find which step is wrong. Please kind to help me to figure it out.

--- Update 02-19

@mk_sta

I remove `authorization_code` then the API could create a transfer, but the transfer couldn't work. It will get an error like this screenshot.

[image]

I thought the error is caused `authorization_code` is used to connect to google ads. Is your transfer work fine?

Reference:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/create

Comment: Have you tried to change authentication method against BigQuery data Transfer API, i.e. set up `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable instead of using OAuth2 authorization code? Is it remain the same issue?

Comment: @mk_sta Yes, I have already set environment `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

Answer (score 0):

After revising your code snippet, I've noticed some points to mention:

1. According to the documentation [pages](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/enable-transfer-service) *BigQuery Data Transfer Service* requires initial service account to own `bigquery.admin` role in order to inherit `bigquery.datasets.update` permission:

> All users that will create transfers must be granted the
>   **bigquery.admin** predefined Cloud IAM role. The bigquery.admin role
>   includes the following BigQuery Data Transfer Service permissions:
>
> `bigquery.transfers.update`
>
> `bigquery.transfers.get`

2. Whenever you invoke `create_transfer_config` function, `authorization_code` is an optional parameter, that might be skipped, launching the different [authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#authentication_strategies) model for transport configuration, depending on the particular user case.

I've tried to execute the above code using service account key associated with my GCP project:

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="<some_path>/[FILE_NAME].json"`

I've made a few adjustments to the source code in order to get rid of `authorization_code` in the transfer config:

```
def run_quickstart():
    from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer_v1
    from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Struct

    client = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.DataTransferServiceClient()

    project = <project-id>
    parent = client.location_path(project, 'us')
    params = Struct()
    params.update({
        "customer_id": <customer-id>
    })

    transfer_config = {
        "destination_dataset_id": "test",
        "display_name": "test",
        "data_source_id": "adwords",
        "params": params
    }

    response = client.create_transfer_config(parent, transfer_config)
    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_quickstart()
```

And that worked for me and I've successfully received response body:

```
name: "projects/.../..."
destination_dataset_id: "test"
display_name: "test"
update_time {
  seconds: 1582044242
  nanos: 441442000
}
data_source_id: "adwords"
next_run_time {
  seconds: 1581897600
}
params {
  fields {
    key: "customer_id"
    value {
      string_value: "XXXX"
    }
  }
}
user_id: <user_id>
dataset_region: "us"
```

Comment: I've managed a bit different scenario (I didn't have Google Ads account), there I was using the same authentication method for both Bigquery API and the source software, but now I see your point, I'll try to get a time to check it and come back here.

Comment: Can you check credentials within [checkValidCreds](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.dataSources/checkValidCreds) method?

Comment: I have used this method and it returns true.

Comment: Although I haven't afforded Google ads account to get any results on research, I will propose you to either change `authorization code` method as described in this [tutorial](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/odbc/a-complete-guide-for-google-bigquery-authentication) or raise an issue [tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to the developer groups, as in my presumption the problem appeared with OAuth `authorization code` validation.